# How to add padding when vertical scroll is enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I have a list of items, for which I am showing vertical scroll(**overflow-y: auto;**) when the height reaches `200px`. but I want to add `padding-right:20px` when the scroll is enabled else I dont want `padding-right`.
I know using jquery we can check height and apply but I am using angularjs so even though dom is loaded my jquery is not getting applied, I tried adding after `window.load` also but no success.

```
ul{
      list-style:none;
      padding-left:0;
      margin-left:0;
      margin-top: 20px;
      padding-left: 5px;
      padding-right: 20px;
      overflow-y:auto;
      height:200px
    }
```

In the above style I have added padding-right20px; this I want only applied when vertical scroll is enabled. Here is my **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5a2r84tk/)** please let me know any suggestions to obtain this. Here is one more fiddle when height is more than 200px, **[Fiddle with scroll enabled](https://jsfiddle.net/zgq39y43/)**

Comment: May I know why do you want to add this padding-right?

Comment: when vertical scroll is enabled if I dont add padding-right:20px then list items will flow inside vertical bar.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the case. When scrollbar gets shown `li` width is automatically reduced (at least in Chrome). Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5a2r84tk/1/ ... if you inspect any of the `li` the computed width shown is 265px. Now if you click on `Create one` scrollbar gets displayed and width of `li` becomes 248px.

Comment: Yeah you are right but still it looks like li is attached to scroll, which I dont want so I am adding padding-right, in my project the li are styles to look like card so it needs padding. Thank you for reply I mean it :-), got the solution from avnesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ul ng-style="list.length>7 ? {'padding-right': '20px','overflow-y':'auto'}:{'padding-right': '0'}"> ... </ul>
```

Css:

```
  ul {
    list - style: none;

    padding - left: 0;
    margin - left: 0;
    margin - top: 20 px;
    padding - left: 5 px;

    height: 200 px
}
li {
    background: gray;
    color: #fff;
    margin - bottom: 10 px;
}
.container {
    width: 300 px
}
```

Will work for you.